# How do I print a single PowerPoint slide as a poster?

Tags: printing, microsoft-powerpoint

I have a single PowerPoint slide and I want to print it as a poster (2ft by 3ft).  I do not have a "Print as Poster" option in File/Print.

I would like to print the slide on multiple pages and then tape the pages together to create a poster.

Similar question: https://superuser.com/questions/210793/good-software-for-printing-a-poster

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save the PowerPoint slide as a `.jpeg` and then use a different software (such as the ones mentioned in your link) to print as a poster.

In PowerPoint 2007 (or 2010):
Go to the Ribbon Start Menu, click `Save As`, then `Other Formats`:

[image]

Then in the dialog box that appears, under where you can name the file, there is a drop-down menu for all the formats you can choose from:

[image]

Choose `.jpeg` (or another photo format), name the file, and choose `Save`.  If you have more than one slide, it will ask you:

[image]

If you choose `Every Slide`, it will create a separate `.jpeg` for every slide and tell you where they are stored, like so:

[image]

(the blacked-listed text is the file location).

Then, as I suggested earlier, just open the photo in another program and print on multiple pages.

Comment: +1, but really you should save as a PNG if you're going to be printing it out afterwards -- don't want to lose any more quality than you have to!

Comment: okay, PNG then! it has an option for that too.